# Adding a cell value/reference into an another cell with a new approach

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know there are many different solutions to do this but I hope I can find a solution to my problem.

I am designing a contract from a template and in contract there are cells which contains the value of "Company Name" ; lets assume that Company name is in cell A2 , in any part of contract I need to use the value of "Company Name" which has been kept in cell A2.

Normally all I had to do is using formula like this  "=A2" or I can use smart tag feature and use  _smarttag instead of A2 reference in required cells.

But in my contract cause of contents of the contract and it's cells I need to use Company name inside many cells with texts.

Although all I had to do is ="TEXT TEXT"  & A2  to concat text and formula value, but cause of the text field length Excel doesn't let me add Company Name data to cell and asks me to use CONCATENATE which will lead me to write many many CONCATENATE formula cause of many lines in many cells.

So to solve my problem all I am seeking if there is any way to add "Company Name Ref" by just getting in cell by F2 key and find the correct place in text to add & A2 & and use that ref.

Yes I know it can be done by VB and it can be done with changing type of cell to formula and CONCATENATE text and formula or even it can be done by adding many new rows.

However I am trying to find out if excel is clever enough to understand that I am requesting a ref data inside the cell while cell type is text.

Maybe some pattern or regex coding in cell to solve my problem.

Comment: if the cell content is too long for excel, then excel is probably not the best place to create a contract. I suggest you learn how to do this in Word with mail merge.

Comment: What do you mean with text field length? I inserted in cell `A2` an example name with 1000 characters. I gave this specific cell the name `CompanyName` and then used this e.g., via `="text " & CompanyName`. If this does not work, please make your issue more explicit with a reproducible example.

Comment: @gns100 I agree with you ; most of the time I use Letter & Envolope feature of Word as like as you mentioned ; instead I use Excel as a database and call the fields from Excel into Word. but in this case I was searching the advance featre of excel if i exists.

Answer (score 1):

No, what you eventually asked is not possible in Excel without using some programming, either your own VBA or someone else's VBA or other programming via an Add-In that does what you wish.

Excel is not itself a programming environment. It is built to display results and do certain things (admittedly hundreds of them) to enhance that "display-ment." It will seek to read that data in many, many disparate places, and as mentioned, manipulate it. But it will not do things outside its normal milieu.

For you to use material like your CompanyName you must write a formula. It can be as simple as your `="TEXT TEXT" & A2`, but nonetheless, it MUST be a formula.

With no statement whatever about your formula, or any particular formula, working or not, for any reason but certainly including those that run up against some limitation in Excel's capabilities, what you want cannot happen because if Excel regards a cell to be Text, it will not in any non-programming way regard that Text as an active formula.

So you can never succeed with something on the order of `="TEXT TEXT" & A2` being placed in a cell formatted as Text but still working as a formula.

You CAN fill cells with text, and if clever enough with the exact situation you could use VBA to render that text into material VBA could then manipulate as or into a real formula and write it into any output VBA can write to. But without that programming (not limited to VBA itself), you cannot do it.

So you must not format the cells you wish the formula to work in as Text. Anything else, basically, though some formatting would surely be a bit unsatisfactory. (The formula might work, but the formatted output might be unfortunate. For instance, it might add the letters "horsie" after the contents so the cell shows "IBMhorsie", probably unfortunate in writing a contract. But the formula would have been operable, rather than inoperable. So working, but unfortunate.)

You will need to compose the pieces of contract in separate cells. Say, one clause/paragraph per cell. Each piece would be a part that starts at the beginning or right after where the company name goes, and end at the next point the company name needs to appear or at the end of the clause/paragraph.

So, perhaps those pieces go into column B. B1 has TEXTTEXTTEXT in it and then you want the company name to appear in the end result. After the company name appears you want more text, perhaps BLAHBLAHBLAH. The the company name or other thing should appear. And perhaps you end with YADAYADAYADA. So B1:B3 have text to use in the clause/paragraph and A1 has the company name.

You have to write the text anyway so why not this way? Just press `Enter` and move down to the next cell in the work column when you reach the company name.

These pieces may be any length that Excel will accept in a Text formatted cell. I believe that is on the order of 32,767 characters, but perhaps it is more or less. Whatever it is... it doesn't matter in any material way.

Then in the output area of your spreadsheet, perhaps a completely separate sheet so things to make the work easier on the composition page do not affect the desired result's appearance, you will write formulas based on the following formula:

```
=CONCAT( MID(B1, (SEQUENCE(1, 1+INT(LEN(B1)/255), 0, 255) + 1), 255) )
```

You'll copy all but the `=` and put together your text joining formula.

The formula above will read the text in cell B1 255 characters at a time until it has an array of all the pieces (the last piece probably being shorter 'cause B1 likely doesn't have a length exactly divisible by 255). It then concatenates those pieces back together into the single string you typed into B1.

And Excel is happy, happy, happy with that because while it won't read more than 255 characters from a pure text entry to use in a formula, it will happily use far, far more text than that in a formula if produced by its own functions in the formula.

That's why each piece of text can be however long it needs to be:  the formula will break it into however many pieces of 255 characters it needs to plus one probably shorter piece and feed those pieces into `CONCAT()` and Excel will be happy.

So then your formula for a contract piece with 15,000 characters need not look like:

```
=CONCATENATE(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12,B13,B14,B15,B16,B17,B18,B19,B20,B21,B22,B23,B24,B25,B26,B27,B28,B29,B30,B31,B32,B33,B34,B35,B36,B37,B38,B39,B40,B41,B42,B43,B44,B45,B46,B47,B48,B49,B50,B51,B52,B53,B54,B55,B56,B57,B58,B59)
```

which, as you might guess, or I wouldn't have done it for the answer, was not actually hard to create (not "write"... "create" using easy string building techniques), nor did it take much time. But honestly, even that would be obnoxious.

So, none of it. No 200 terms in your `CONCATENATE()`.

You would still need to write something like (using my above example for a clause/paragraph):

```
=CONCAT(
 CONCAT( MID(B1, (SEQUENCE(1, 1+INT(LEN(B1)/255), 0, 255) + 1), 255) ),
 & " " & A1 & " ",
 CONCAT( MID(B2, (SEQUENCE(1, 1+INT(LEN(B2)/255), 0, 255) + 1), 255) )
 & " " & A1 & " ",
 CONCAT( MID(B3, (SEQUENCE(1, 1+INT(LEN(B3)/255), 0, 255) + 1), 255) ) )
```

which would collect the piece in B1, add a space, the company name, and a space, collect the piece in B2, and so on, until done. And all you have to do is type the first `CONCAT(`, copy the formula piece and paste it here, write the `& " " & A1 & " "`, then copy those two parts, the formula piece and the reference to the company name cell (or other piece of particular data) and paste it as many times as you need. Then edit each pair to change the cell in the B column to the next one (you see the first above has B1, the next piece has B2, the last piece has B3), and if you are inserting something other than the company name in one or more spots, edit the "A1" part in appropriate lines to be the cell containing the required part.

Not nearly the formula writing nightmare imagined. It won't write itself, but it's not hard to physically create, nor hard to understand what was being done a year or two from now when wanting to upgrade it or turn it over to someone so you can take your promotion.

You seem new to Excel. Before you try using it with Mail Merge in Word, you might wish to gain some experience. This could carry you over while learning. And if you already have good Word skills, just stick inside Word. It can easily take your re-usable material to use in Fields placed in the text, or even with Mail Merge.

*(Though honestly, Mail Merge would really not be on point for a single, unique document needing to be produced. Doable, and a perfectly good solution, but... overkill. It is intended for 2 to a billion documents using 2 to a billion sets of information, not for a single document. Simply using Fields to place the material in a single, unique Word document would be effort enough. But results matter, so going that route is certainly valid and doable, and not any kind of "strange" — just some kind of overkill.)*

Comment: it is not my expected answer however from the explanation I see there is no other options exist rather than yours; I should go to a solution like which gns100 mentioned at his comment. Meanwhile I am not new to Word or Excel however I came to a point which seems highly undoable request from  a friend; and wanted to ask to community so maybe it might be a chance for me to learn a possible a new information  for me which remains in very deep to dig out.